# How can I solve "Unreachable code" error in my kotlin project?

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, android-lifecycle

**SplashActivity.kt**

```
 @AndroidEntryPoint
    @SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")
    class SplashActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
        private val viewModel: SplashScreenViewModel by viewModels()
        private val tokenManager = TokenManager(this)
        val activity = this
        private val errMsg = "Bir hata ile karşılaşıldı."
    
        private fun navigateToMain(isTokenExist: Boolean) {
            val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("isTokenExist", isTokenExist)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
                splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { true }
            }
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    
            if (viewModel.state.value.error) {
                Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity, errMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                tokenManager.getRefreshToken().collect { refreshToken ->
                    if (refreshToken != null) {
                        if (viewModel.state.value.error) {
                            delay(2000)
                            activity.navigateToMain(false)
                        }
                        viewModel.state.collect {
                            activity.navigateToMain(!it.error)
                        }
                        activity.viewModel.refreshAccessToken(refreshToken) //unreachable code warning
                    } else {
                        delay(2000)
                        activity.navigateToMain(false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**SplashScreenViewModel.kt**

```
 @HiltViewModel
    class SplashScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val tokenManager: TokenManager
    ) : ViewModel() {
    
        private val _state = MutableStateFlow(SplashScreenState())
        val state: StateFlow<SplashScreenState> = _state.asStateFlow()
    
    
        fun refreshAccessToken(refreshToken: String) {
    
            viewModelScope.launch {
                try {
                    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                    loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient
                        .Builder()
                        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                        //.authenticator(AuthAuthenticator(tokenManager))
                        .build()
    
                    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(okHttpClient)
                        .build()
    
                    val service = retrofit.create(RegisterService::class.java)
    
                    val response = service.refreshToken(model = RefreshToken(refreshToken))
    
                    if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                        val newAccessToken = response.body()?.access_token
                        val newRefreshToken = response.body()?.refresh_token
                        if (newAccessToken != null && newRefreshToken != null) {
                            tokenManager.saveAccessToken(newAccessToken)
                            tokenManager.saveRefreshToken(newRefreshToken)
                        }
                    }
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            completed = true
                        )
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            error = true,
                            completed = true
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    data class SplashScreenState(
        val error: Boolean = false,
        var completed:Boolean = false
    )
```

**TokenManager.kt**

```
class TokenManager(private val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        private val ACCESS_TOKEN  = stringPreferencesKey("access_token")
        private val REFRESH_TOKEN = stringPreferencesKey("refresh_token")
        private val EXPIRATION_TIME = longPreferencesKey("expiration_time")
    }

    fun getAccessToken(): Flow<String?> {
        return context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
            preferences[ACCESS_TOKEN]
        }
    }

    suspend fun saveAccessToken(token: String) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[ACCESS_TOKEN] = token
            val expirationTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            preferences[EXPIRATION_TIME] = expirationTime + 86400 * 1000
        }
    }

    fun getAccessTokenExpirationTime(): Flow<Long?> {
        return context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
            preferences[EXPIRATION_TIME]
        }
    }

    suspend fun deleteAccessToken() {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences.remove(ACCESS_TOKEN)
        }
    }

    fun getRefreshToken(): Flow<String?> {
        return context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
            preferences[REFRESH_TOKEN]
        }
    }

    suspend fun saveRefreshToken(token: String) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[REFRESH_TOKEN] = token
            val expirationTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            preferences[EXPIRATION_TIME] = expirationTime + 86400 * 1000
        }
    }

    suspend fun deleteRefreshToken() {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences.remove(REFRESH_TOKEN)
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an Unreachable code warning. I shared my splash activity and viewodel codes above. I think that the codes I made are correct, but there is a part that I do not like, why android studio gives this warning.

```
  viewModel.state.collect {
                        activity.navigateToMain(!it.error)
                    }
                    activity.viewModel.refreshAccessToken(refreshToken) // --> Unreachable code warning
```

In this line of code will **activity.navigateToMain(!it.error)**

not work when there is a change in state anyway?

so there is no change in the first time, then it will not work and the following code will work so  **activity.viewModel.refreshAccessToken(refreshToken)** right ?

If this is the case, the logic is correct, but if navigateToMain works, then it is normal to give an Unreachable code warning at the first time because after navigating, it goes to the mainActivity and this terminates the splashActivity, then the **activity.viewModel.refreshAccessToken(refreshToken)** line does not work. Is it right what I did? or is there an error? I'm not sure so I wanted to ask can you help?

Answer (score 2):

A StateFlow never completes, so when you call `collect` on `state`, none of the code below the `collect` call will ever be reached, because `collect` will never return.

---

Edit:

The way you have your StateFlow set up, it will have a `complete == true` value when you are ready to navigate. So the quick and easy fix for your code is to replace

```
viewModel.state.collect {
    activity.navigateToMain(!it.error)
}
```

with

```
val refreshResult = viewModel.state.first { it.completed }
activity.navigateToMain(!refreshResult.error)
```

The `first` function suspends until a value is emitted that means the criteria in the lambda, and then it returns that value.

Also, have this `if (viewModel.state.value.error) {` block where you navigate away from the screen, but then allow the rest of your logic to continue. You either need to call `return @launch` inside this `if` block or wrap the code below it in an `else` block.

You also need to remove `(Dispatchers.IO)` after your `launch` call. There is no blocking code in your coroutine that would require it, and you need to be on `Main` to navigate between activities.

Optional: This is how I would design the ViewModel class to avoid the possibility of redundantly restarting the fetch if the Fragment is recreated and calls `refreshAccessToken()` again.

```
class SplashScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tokenManager: TokenManager
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(SplashScreenState())
    val state: StateFlow<SplashScreenState> = _state.asStateFlow()

    private val refreshJob: Job? = null

    fun refreshAccessToken(refreshToken: String) {
        if (refreshJob != null) {
            return
        }
        refreshJob = viewModelScope.launch {
            // your original code  

            // After all code from your original coroutine, if you want to 
            // support ability to call this function again to do another refresh:
            refreshJob = null
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: can you share example code ?

Comment: I would have to see your TokenManager class. But it's not trivial to redesign the whole thing, especially without knowing everything your app needs to do and how it should behave.

Comment: I shared my token manager you can see

Comment: Actually, as I look at it closer, I think using a Flow to hold the results of the token refresh is OK. You do need to preserve the ongoing work in case the fragment is recreated while waiting for results, so a hot flow is needed (you could use Deferred, but we probably want to have the ability to refresh again). I updated with some recommendations.